# how to align the item equally to the column title

Tags: android

how to align the content to its column title, i have here the sample below

Name-----------------Number-----------------Age

Yan 1232312  25

here is my xml code to view the sqlite database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Name" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
           android:id="@+id/Hot"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Number" >
            </TextView>
        </TableRow>

          </TableLayout>
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSqlInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Name" >
            </TextView>

        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this one is the my Activityclass to view the xml,can you please teach me where to put the tablelayout parameter thanks

```
    `public class SQLView extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.sqlview);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);
    row.addView(text);
    table.addView(row);


            TableLayout.LayoutParams l = 
                new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    l.weight = 1;

         tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvSqlInfo);
            HotorNot info = new HotorNot(this);
            info.open();
            String data = info.getData();
            info.close();
            tv.setText(data);



here is my database class

    public class HotorNot {

        public static final String KEY_ROWID= "_id";
        public static final String KEY_NAME= "Person_Names";
        public static final String KEY_HOT= "personHOT";

        private static final String DATABASE_name= "HotorNotdb";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE= "PeopleTable";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION= 1;

        private DbHelper ourHelper;
        private final Context ourContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

        public static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

            public DbHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + 
                        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +    
                        KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                        KEY_HOT + " TEXT NOT NULL);"


                );
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLES IF EXIST" + DATABASE_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }


        }
        public HotorNot(Context c){
            ourContext = c;

        }
        public HotorNot open() throws SQLException {
            ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close(){
            ourHelper.close();
        }
        public long createEntry(String name, String hotness) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            cv.put(KEY_HOT, hotness);
        return  ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);


        }
        public String getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] columns = new String []{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_HOT};
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            String results = "";

            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
            int iHotness = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_HOT);

            for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
                results = results  + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iHotness) + " " + c.getString(iName)+"\n";

            }

            return results;


        }
        public String getName(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] columns= new String []{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,KEY_HOT};
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "_" + l, null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null ){

                c.moveToFirst();
                String name = c.getString(1);
                return name;
            }

            return null;
        }
        public String getHotness(long l) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String[] columns= new String []{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,KEY_HOT};
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null);
            if (c != null ){

                c.moveToFirst();
                String hotness = c.getString(2);
                return hotness;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn't find a simple answer when I googled.

Here's my code how I did it, it's from the game I'm working on, it only has
two columns but more can easily be added. The rows are being sorted by highest
score.

This is the activity where you see the highscore:

```
    public class Highscore extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
        TextView tvname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        TextView tvscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
        SQLScore info = new SQLScore(this);
        info.open();
        String name = info.getName();
        String score = info.getScore();
        info.close();
        tvname.setText(name);
        tvscore.setText(score);
        }
}
```

And this is the XML for it:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Score" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Name" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvScore"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="Score" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally, the methods in my SQL-handler file:

```
public String getName() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null,     null, KEY_SCORE + " DESC", "10");
    String result = "";

    int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iName) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}

public String getScore() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_SCORE + " DESC", "10");
    String result = "";

    int iScore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iScore) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Basically, you're fetching the rows but you need one method returning data from each column within every row. I'm pretty new to android-programming, so my solution might not be perfect but this worked for me at least.